# Clojure - pass component to functions not executed during start or stop

Tags: clojure, architecture

In the README of Stuart Sierra's component, there is a function [`add-user`](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component/blob/master/README.md#creating-components) that is given as an example, but not seen anywhere else :

```
(defn add-user [database username favorite-color]
  (execute-insert (:connection database)
    "INSERT INTO users (username, favorite_color)"
    username favorite-color))
```

I imagine it could be executed (for instance) on a web server route. I have no trouble imagining that `username` and `favorite-colour` would be parameters to that route, and thus readily available when calling `add-user`.

I guess that having this would make the `database` component of the `web-server` (for example) component.
However I am having some trouble figuring where the `database` component *instance* parameter of `add-user` should come from exactly.

I feel that directly accessing the `system` (ie. doing `(:database my-system-ns/system))`) to retrieve it would defeat part of the purpose of using components in the first place.

For instance if I am using pedestal, I may have my pedestal component (who has access to the database component) set up this key :

```
::bootstrap/routes #(deref #'my-routes-ns/routes)
```

And this would be something like that :

```
;; in my-routes-ns
(defroutes routes [[[ "/add-user" {:post add-user-handler} ]]])

;; same function again for clarity
(defn add-user [database username favorite-color]
  (execute-insert (:connection database)
    "INSERT INTO users (username, favorite_color)"
    username favorite-color))

;; my route handler
(defn add-user-handler [request]
  ;; How do I get access to the database component from here ?
  (add-user database "user" "red"))
```

How do I get access to my `database` component in this example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, [the README of component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component/blob/master/README.md#web-applications) suggest create a closure over one or more component,

```
(defn app-routes
  "Returns the web handler function as a closure over the
  application component."
  [app-component]
  ;; Instead of static 'defroutes':
  (web-framework/routes
   (GET "/" request (home-page app-component request))
   (POST "/foo" request (foo-page app-component request))
   (not-found "Not Found")))

(defrecord WebServer [http-server app-component]
  component/Lifecycle
  (start [this]
    (assoc this :http-server
           (web-framework/start-http-server
             (app-routes app-component))))
  (stop [this]
    (stop-http-server http-server)
    this))

(defn web-server
  "Returns a new instance of the web server component which
  creates its handler dynamically."
  []
  (component/using (map->WebServer {})
                   [:app-component]))
```

Answer (score 2):

In a typical application, you might have a `web-server` component that depends (see `component/using`) on your `database` component, and a collection of public functions associated with the `database` component that its consumers could call to query the database.

The `web-server` component will then be responsible for setting up your request handler and starting a listener (like Jetty). This will involve taking the `database` component and injecting it into your handler, perhaps by partial application (if your handler looks like `(defn handler [database request] …)`, say), so that it can call `add-user` on the actual `database` component.

Note that depending on the design of your app, your setup may not match the above exactly – for example,`web-server` could only use the `database` component through one or more layers of intermediate components.

Comment: I get the idea, but I am unsure about how to apply it in practice, for I don't think I can pass it to `defroutes` for instance.

Comment: Ah apparently the intended use is to put it into the request from a middleware / interceptor. I have to try that : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/12-j2DeSLEI/discussion

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a possibility. In [Rook](https://github.com/AvisoNovate/rook) you could use argument resolvers for this purpose. Back to Pedestal, you could also use `expand-routes` instead of `defroutes`; that would allow you to build up your route definitions using any required components during `web-server` startup.